# Missing helper file helpers/addressable/uri.rb in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to set up a Debian squeeze server with Rails 3.1.8. The app starts perfectly fine in development, but in production mode I'm getting this stacktrace below. Is there something wrong my ruby build? Any recommended flags for squeeze?

> > Writing PID to /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/tmp/thin.2.pid
> >     Using rack adapter
> >     Exiting!
> >     /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:306:in `rescue in depend_on': Missing helper file helpers/addressable/uri.rb (LoadError)
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:301:in`depend_on'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:135:in`block in modules_for_helpers'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `map!'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in`modules_for_helpers'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:89:in `modules_for_helpers'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:95:in`helper'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:159:in `default_helper_module!'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:22:in`block in inherited'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:22:in `class_eval'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:22:in`inherited'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/action_controller/metal/hide_actions.rb:32:in `inherited'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:130:in`inherited'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.8/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in`block (2 levels) in with'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/releases/20121028215215/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`require'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in`load_dependency'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in`require_or_load'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load_missing_constant'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in`block in const_missing'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in`const_missing'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:212:in `const_missing_from_s3_library'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/inherited_resources-1.3.1/app/controllers/inherited_resources/base.rb:11:in`'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/inherited_resources-1.3.1/app/controllers/inherited_resources/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`require'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in`load_dependency'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in`require_or_load'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load_missing_constant'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in`block in const_missing'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in`const_missing'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/aws-s3-0.6.3/lib/aws/s3/extensions.rb:212:in `const_missing_from_s3_library'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-7d09a0ac8252/lib/active_admin/base_controller/menu.rb:2:in`'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-7d09a0ac8252/lib/active_admin/base_controller/menu.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`require'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in`load_dependency'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-7d09a0ac8252/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb:2:in`'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-7d09a0ac8252/lib/active_admin/application.rb:222:in `before_filter'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/releases/20121028215215/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:91:in`block in '
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-7d09a0ac8252/lib/active_admin.rb:71:in `setup'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/releases/20121028215215/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:1:in`'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in`block in load'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in`load'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in`each'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `block in <class:Engine>'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/current/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/current/config.ru:3:in`require'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/current/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in`instance_eval'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/current/config.ru:1:in`new'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/current/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in`eval'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:33:in `load'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:42:in`for'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:169:in `load_adapter'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:73:in`start'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:187:in `run_command'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:152:in`run!'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in`load'
> >         from /home/railsapps/localhost_production/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `'

Comment: helpers/addressable/uri.rb is the wrong path, the file is one level below in core_ext folder. Why would it be wrong?

Comment: I see that also?  I assume you require 'uri' somewhere in your code,  grep (search) for require*uri in your code and post the results.